# distribution of maximum of i.i.d. variables

Tags: probability

I'm doing a problem where we let consider the probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$  and let $X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}$ be i.i.d random variables. If the distribution of $X_{1}$ is $(\delta_{1} + \delta_{2} + \delta_{3})/3$, and we compute the distribution of  $Y=max\{X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}\}$.

I know that the distribution function $P(Y\leq y)=P(X_{1} \leq y, X_{2} \leq y,X_{3} \leq y)=P(X_{1} \leq y)^{3}$ so can I just say the distribution of Y is  $\delta_{1}^3$? I'm a little confused about the narrations here--- since we have i.i.d. variables, then why can't we just say that $X_{1}$ has distribution $\delta_{1}$ instead of $(\delta_{1} + \delta_{2} + \delta_{3})/3$?

Comment: Who is $\delta_i$? The Dirac distribution in 1 or something else?

Comment: @Momo Oh! So the problem didn't say anything about what it is. But does it really affect the result?

Comment: Of course that the distribution of $X_1$ affects the result. See my answer for an attempt under assumptions that deltas are Dirac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Dirac distributions for $\delta$:

$$
P(X_1\le y)=
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } x<1 \\
\frac{1}{3} & \text{if } 1\le x<2 \\
\frac{2}{3} & \text{if } 2\le x<3 \\
1, & \text{if } x\ge 3 \\
\end{cases}
$$

From which you can derive:
$$
P(Y\le y)=
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } x<1 \\
\frac{1}{27} & \text{if } 1\le x<2 \\
\frac{8}{27} & \text{if } 2\le x<3 \\
1, & \text{if } x\ge 3 \\
\end{cases}
$$

So $Y=\frac{1}{27}\delta_1+\frac{7}{27}\delta_2+\frac{19}{27}\delta_3$

However, it might be more intuitive not to go through CDF for this discrete case:

$P(Y=1)=P(X_1=1)P(X_2=1)P(X_3)=1=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3=\frac{1}{27}$

...etc

Comment: Thank you for your comment! This all makes perfect sense. Now if we don't assume this is a dirac measure. can I just say the distribution of the max is $\delta ^{3}$? I think the outcome of your example is also $\delta ^{3}$ given that is a dirac measure.

Comment: You cannot say that. $\delta_x$ just concentrates the whole probability mass in x, and it is 0 outside of x. $(\delta_1+\delta_2+\delta_3)/3$ concentrates the probability of 1/3 in each of the points with coordinates 1, 2, respectively 3. What makes you think that you can multiply Diracs like that?

Comment: Thanks! I now see where I was wrong.